# Merge data frame using another row if one row has null value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframe that need to be merged(both data frames are similar to the image attached).

I want to first try merging on Res ID, but if a particular row has Null value in Res ID, I want that row to be merged using the Geohash_7 column. Is there any good way to do this.

Basically I want to merge on a column but if that column contains a null value, I want to merge using a different column for that specific row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.fillna()` to fill `nan` values with the values of column `Geohash_7` when it has null values.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Geohash_7': ['ttnf48s', 'ttnccw3'], 'Geohash_8': ['ttnf48sj', 'ttnccw3r'], 'Res ID': [np.nan, 217]})
>>> df
  Geohash_7 Geohash_8  Res ID
0   ttnf48s  ttnf48sj     NaN
1   ttnccw3  ttnccw3r   217.0
>>> df['Res ID'].fillna(df.Geohash_7)
0    ttnf48s
1        217
Name: Res ID, dtype: object
```